# Excel VBA - replace cells as value for particular formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I have the big Excel with a lot of formulas. I would like to save this Excel as values but only for some formulas not for all.

I use this VBA script - but this replaces all formulas by values. How can I replace for example only all cells which contain formula SUM - maybe which contain =SUM(

```
Sub Saveasvalue()
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wsh.Cells.Copy
        wsh.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add a checking condition like below to test if the cell contains SUM formula.

```
Sub Saveasvalue()
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each rng In wsh.UsedRange
            If InStr(1, rng.Formula, "SUM(", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                rng.Value = rng.Value
            End If
        Next rng
    Next
End Sub
```